# futures timeout error in the telegram bot, concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

I have created a telegram bot. where I am asking the users to send the location.

```
import aioschedule as schedule
import asyncio
from asyncio import futures


@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery(pattern=r'sendloc'))
async def sendlocation(event):
    sender = await event.get_input_sender()
    my_user = await bot.get_entity(sender.user_id)
    userId = my_user.id
    async with bot.conversation(userId) as conv:
        await conv.send_message('receiving', buttons=[Button.request_location(text='send Location', resize=10)])
        try:
            response = await conv.get_response()
        except futures.TimeoutError as e:
            await conv.cancel_all()
            return
        conv.send_message('location accepted')  


async def methodToSendLocation():
    users = pd.read_csv('telegramId.csv')
    for user in users['Telegram ID']:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(user, 'send location', buttons=Button.inline('sendloc'))
        except ValueError as e:
            print('Error occurred for user: {telId}'.format(telId=user))

def main():
    '''start the bot'''
    bot.start()
    schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(methodToSendLocation)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    bot.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

what does my program do?

1. It will run every day at 11:00 AM.
2. It will fetch the telegram Id from the CSV file and send a message to the users to send the location and we process the location.

My Query:
Sometimes there occurs a timeout error in `sendlocation` method of my program and recently I observed that for some users timeout error occurred within a minute after the user clicks the `send Location` button.

I am not able to understand why the error occurred in a very short interval.
And sometimes there has been a delay to send the location to the bot after the user clicks the `send Location` button.

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 118, in sendlocation
    response = await conv.get_response()
  File "C:\Users\Swarnim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 449, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 450, in <module>
    main()
  File "app.py", line 444, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 471, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 438, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1451, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/home/epluser/.venv/automation/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py", line 443, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "app.py", line 121, in sendlocation
```

Comment: Please send the full error message including stack trace

Comment: added stack trace